# why my jsonParser using Streaming API use much more memory

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have code which jsonparse the whole file:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, ValueClass<V>> space = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ValueClass<V>> ();
Map<String, ValueClass<V>> map = mapper.readValue(new FileReader(fileName)...);
for each entry of map:
      space.put(entry.getKey(), entry.value());
```

the memory used to parse the file is large and is much more than the size of the file itself. To save memory, I decided to replace the code with jsonparse streaming API as follows:

```
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, ValueClass<V>> space = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ValueClass<V>> ();
            JsonFactory f = new MappingJsonFactory();
            JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(new File(fileName);
            JsonToken current;
            current = jp.nextToken();
            if (current != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                show error and return;
            }
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
           key = jp.getCurrentName();
           current = jp.nextToken();
           if (key != null) {
               if (current == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                   mem_before=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                       value = mapper.readValue(jp, ValueClass.class); (1)
                   mem_after=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
                   mem_diff = mem_after - mem_before; (2)
                       space.put(key, value); (3)
               }
               else jp.skipChildren();
           else jp.skipChildren();
      }
```

however, it spends even much more memory than parsing the whole file once. And it shows the memory increase is due to (1) (I detect the allocatedMemory using Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory before (1) and after (1) to obtain difference)

shouldn't using streaming API save memory, according to http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily and other article said?

**EDIT**

@StaxMan: Thanks for answering me. Looks like you are very familiar with memory consumption we should expect.

My purpose is to load content from file to memory, so that I do not need to search content from file. so I do need all the content in map all the time.

The reason I think streaming may help is: if loading entire file as one object, I guess besides consuming memory for the map variable: space, we need a large additional memory to parse the whole file, which is a big burden; but by using streaming, although we still need the same memory for the map variable:space, we only need a small amount of additional memory to parse each entry of a file, this additional memory is small because we reuse it to parse each entry instead of parsing the whole file. Doesn’t it save memory therefore? Please correct me if I am wrong.

I understand memory size may be more than file size. But first I do not understand why it need so much more than file (2.7 times of file size in my case); second, I do not understand why with streaming I spend even more memory (even double of without using streaming). Memory leak? But I do not see any problem of my code. should have been at least no more than 2.7 times.

Besides, do you know how to estimate memory consumption of an object such as each entry of my map variable space?

Comment: `ObjectMapper#readValue()` is not for streaming. It is for creating in-memory structure.

Comment: I am using Full Data Binding (POJO). see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes. Is't it the right way to parse an class? then what is the right way? Thanks.

Comment: Did you force a gc before checking freeMemory()? And at what points did you check? Also, might be easier to keep an eye on heap use with a tool like jconsole or jvisualvm.

Comment: @user389955 With streaming, you should create the objects manually, as you see the tokens. Though I think you will not get (much) lower memory usage as with reading with non-streaming Jackson. (Each object requires additional memory, so I would not expect anything close to a UTF-8 encoded file's size. Probably 2-5 times larger.)

Comment: @Gábor Bakos: I updated my original post with line (2) and (3). LIne(2) is the way I use to collect allocated memory.  In fact if I remove line (3). I will even get negative memory_diff at last.So I doubt line(3) led to memory leak which led to large memory. Do you think that may be the reason?

Comment: @Gábor Bakos: you said: "you should create the objects manually". Do you mean manually parse EACH detail item like: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes, or do you mean using JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree() when parsing each entry, like http://www.ngdata.com/parsing-a-large-json-file-efficiently-and-easily/?

Comment: Note: the latter link said: "this file can be read using a combination of stream and tree-model parsing. Each individual record is read in a tree structure, but the file is never read in its entirety into memory, making it possible to process JSON files gigabytes in size while using minimal memory." I tried to use this way and thought mapper.readValue(jp...) and JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree() are the same thing. Isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the internals of Jackson. The mapper might need a bit more memory than the `jp.readValueAsTree()`, but for certain cases only for the construction, later it might require less.

Comment: @user389955 Jackson never reads the whole file input in memory before parsing: even when using `ObjectMapper`, streaming `JsonParser` is used to only keep minimal state in memory. This is why streaming parser probably won't help a lot -- mapper already uses it. As to estimation, you may want to google for that: there are articles that explain how to do rough estimations; and perhaps even libraries that can do this using reflection if you want.

Comment: @StacMax: I went over the source code of readValue() as well and realized that it also uses token to parse the whole file so not much additional memory are wasted. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you explained what you are trying to achieve. For example, do you absolutely need all the values in memory at all times? Or would it be possible to process values one at a time, and avoid building that `Map` with all keys, values.

Your second attempt does not make much sense without explanation what you are trying to do there; but essentially amount of memory used should be space for value POJOs, keys, and `Map` that contains them. This may be more than input JSON or less, but it really depends on kind of content you are dealing with. Strings, for example, will consume memory memory in JVM than JSON file: most characters in UTF-8 are single byte, whereas each `char` in JVM is 16-bit value (UCS-2 encoded). Further, whereas JSON Strings have 3 or 4 byte overhead (quotes, separators), memory overhead for `java.lang.String` is more like 16 or 24 bytes per String.

Similarly, `Map`s consume quite a bit of memory for structure that JSON file does not need. JSON has couple of separators per entry, maybe 6 - 8 bytes (depending on indentation is used). Java Maps, on the other hand, have bigger per-entry overhead (maybe 16 bytes?) in addition to String keys (with above-mentioned overhead) and POJO values.

So: all in all, it is not uncommon that objects in memory may consume bit more memory than what JSON file itself contains.